# Java Enums: Implementing methods After Declaration?

Tags: java

Consider the simple example below of implementing a method in an Enum.  One problem with this method is that, when you have a lot of enum instances, you visually can no longer see them all at once, as a list.  That is, if we had many toys, I would like to see "DOLL, SOLDIER, TEDDYBEAR, TRAIN, ETC", together, in one long list, and then after that list I could implement any needed methods, e.g. methods that are abstract in the enum itself.

Is there any way to do this?  Or do you have to implement the methods when you declare the individual enum instances, as in the example below?

```java
public enum Toy {
     DOLL() {
          @Override public void execute() { 
               System.out.println("I'm a doll."); 
          }
     },
     SOLDIER() {
          @Override public void execute() { 
               System.out.println("I'm a soldier."); 
          }
     };
     //abstract method
     public abstract void execute();
}
```

Comment: The way you do this above is the _preferred_ way to do it, FYI.

Comment: What do you mean?  According to what source?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way that comes to mind is to leave the implementation of the abstract methods to separate implementation classes, something like:

```
interface ToyBehaviour {

    void execute();
}

public enum Toy {
     DOLL(new DollBehaviour()),
     SOLDIER(new SoldierBehaviour());

     private final ToyBehaviour behaviour;    

     Toy(ToyBehaviour impl) {

        behaviour = impl;
     }

     public void execute() {

        behaviour.execute();
     }
}

class DollBehaviour implements ToyBehaviour {

    public void execute() { 
        System.out.println("I'm a doll."); 
    }
}
```

This setup would allow you to create behaviour classes in separate files in the case that your implementation has enough complexity to warrant separation.

In the case that the implementation is simple enough to include it into the one `enum` class, you can put the interface and behaviour classes as children of the enum class:

```
public enum Toy {
     // enum values
     DOLL(new DollBehaviour()),
     SOLDIER(new SoldierBehaviour());

     private final ToyBehaviour behaviour;    

     Toy(ToyBehaviour impl) {

        behaviour = impl;
     }

     public void execute() {

        behaviour.execute();
     }

    // behaviour interface
    interface ToyBehaviour {

        void execute();
    }

    // behaviour implementation (sub)classes
    static class DollBehaviour implements ToyBehaviour {

        public void execute() { 
            System.out.println("I'm a doll."); 
        }
    }

    // etc ...
}
```

I would probably opt for the first implementation myself, unless the hierarchy of implementation classes is very trivial.

Answer (score 4):

If you want more compact enum declarations, the only ways I can think of to do it are :

if you can construct your methods out of initializer variables:

```
public enum Toy {
     DOLL("doll"),SOLDIER("soldier");

     private Toy(String name){ this.name=name;}
     public void execute(){ System.out.println("I'm a "+name );}
 }
```

or, slightly more complicated, kind of the same with functions, if the behavior is more complex -

```
abstract class SomeToyMethod {
  abstract void execute();

  public SomeToyMethod DOLL_METHOD = new SomeToyMethod(){ 
     public void execute(){  System.out.println("I'm a doll");})
  public SomeToyMethod SOLDIER_METHOD = new SomeToyMethod(){ 
     public void execute(){  System.out.println("I'm a soldier");})


public enum Toy {
     DOLL(SomeToyMethod,DOLL_METHOD),SOLDIER(SomeToyMethod.SOLDIER_METHOD);

     private Toy(SomeToyMethod method){ this.method=method;}
     public void execute(){ method.execute();}
 }
```

Comment: 'You can't declare abstract methods in enums'. Not true.

Comment: Ah, you're correct - my compiler actually says that's only allowed if you declare enums that implement the abstract method. Thanks for the correction, will correct the above.

Comment: Abstract methods in enums are perfectly legal.

Comment: Steve, I like your first suggestion, but in my case the arguments to the private constructor would be other enums in the list.  You can think of my use-case as the enum instances having relatives which I want to record.  But unfortunately the compiler complains if I you do "DOLL(SOLDIER), SOLDIER(DOLL)"... any workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like:

```
public enum Toy {
    DOLL,
    SOLDIER,
    ANOTHER_TOY;

    public static void execute(Toy toy) {
        switch(toy) {
            case DOLL:
                System.out.println("I'm a doll."); 
                break;
            case SOLDIER:
                System.out.println("I'm a soldier."); 
                break;
            case ANOTHER_TOY:
                System.out.println("I'm another toy."); 
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Not very pretty but it keeps your enum declarations together.

Comment: milk, funny, i actually thought of that, and given the simplicity of my template behaviors it would work fine, but won't this give me a performance hit?  i'll be using these enums in the context of simulations (millions of hits), so i thought the "case:" lookups would slow the program down a bit... what do you think?

Comment: Note that this effectively removes the encapsulation/polymorphism offered by the original.

Comment: Note, you can remove the static and parameter, and switch on `this` instead. Case statements are fast. I like to do this, but only when the switch is defined in the enum itself, and only if the different options are one-liners.

Comment: @Jonah can't imagine the performance hit being significant but Paul Bellora is correct, the encapsulation is reduced.